# How to login to the GUI from commandline

Tags: command-line, login, gui

When I boot up, I sometimes go into tty, execute a few commands and then have to restart the GUI (`gmd`) with

```
sudo service restart gdm
```

I then go to the GUI (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) and have to login.

Occasionally, it freezes up after logging in, and I go through the process again. Is there any way of starting the GUI and loggining in, for example

```
sudo service gdm restart --login myname
```

then it would ask for password (like `sudo` does).

And rather than me switch to GUI then login, I would switch to GUI and everything would be running.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to achieve this with `startx`from the TTY.

If this is not the case you should be able to set that up by creating or editing the `.xinitrc` in your home directory and using the `startx` command. I'm not sure if this is set up in Ubuntu by default or by some other means but there is some useful information [On the Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc)